# python3, how to repeat a list of character

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

Goodmorning, I have a problem with the following function:

```
aminoacids = ['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']

pair_no_change = ['A', 'K']

original_pairs = [['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'],['D', 'E'], ['S', 'F'], ['B', 'C'], ['Y', 'V'], ['K', 'W']]

fq = 5

def frequency(original_pairs, pair_no_change, fq):
    updated_pairs = list(list())
    for pair in original_pairs:
        if pair != pair_no_change:
            pair[0] *= fq
            pair[1] *= fq
            updated_pairs.append([pair[0], pair[1]])
        else:
            continue
    return updated_pairs

updated_pairs = frequency(original_pairs, pair_no_change, fq)
#print(updated_pairs)
for pair in updated_pairs:
    print(pair)
```

this function gives me the following output:

```
['DDDDD', 'EEEEE']
['SSSSS', 'FFFFF']
['BBBBB', 'CCCCC']
['YYYYY', 'VVVVV']
['KKKKK', 'WWWWW']
```

I need an output like:

```
['D','E']
['D','E']
['D','E']
['D','E']
['D','E']
['S','F']
['S','F']
['S','F']
['S','F']
['S','F']
etc.
```

I think that there is something wrong in the way I wrote the for loop, when I wrote pair[0] *= fq.
thank you for your time and answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another for loop at the last.

```
aminoacids = ['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']

pair_no_change = ['A', 'K']

original_pairs = [['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'],['D', 'E'], ['S', 'F'], ['B', 'C'], ['Y', 'V'], ['K', 'W']]

fq = 5

def frequency(original_pairs, pair_no_change, fq):
    updated_pairs = list(list())
    for pair in original_pairs:
        if pair != pair_no_change:
            pair[0] *= fq
            pair[1] *= fq
            updated_pairs.append([pair[0], pair[1]])
        else:
            continue
    return updated_pairs

updated_pairs = frequency(original_pairs, pair_no_change, fq)
#print(updated_pairs)
for pair in updated_pairs:
    for i ,j in zip(list(pair[0]), list(pair[1])):
        print [i,j]
```

**Output:**

```
['D', 'E']
['D', 'E']
['D', 'E']
['D', 'E']
['D', 'E']
['S', 'F']
['S', 'F']
['S', 'F']
['S', 'F']
['S', 'F']
['B', 'C']
['B', 'C']
['B', 'C']
['B', 'C']
['B', 'C']
['Y', 'V']
['Y', 'V']
['Y', 'V']
['Y', 'V']
['Y', 'V']
['K', 'W']
['K', 'W']
['K', 'W']
['K', 'W']
['K', 'W']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making arrays by multiplying, instead of that, just append.
Try this,

```
aminoacids = ['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']

pair_no_change = ['A', 'K']

original_pairs = [['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'],['D', 'E'], ['S', 'F'], ['B', 'C'], ['Y', 'V'], ['K', 'W']]

fq = 5

def frequency(original_pairs, pair_no_change, fq):
    updated_pairs = list(list())

    for pair in original_pairs:
        fq1 = fq
        if pair != pair_no_change:
            # pair[0] *= fq
            # pair[1] *= fq
            while fq1 > 0:
                updated_pairs.append([pair[0], pair[1]])
                fq1 -= 1
        else:
            continue
    return updated_pairs

updated_pairs = frequency(original_pairs, pair_no_change, fq)
#print(updated_pairs)
for pair in updated_pairs:
    print(pair)
```

Answer (score 1):

you want something like this:

```
>>> pair_no_change = ['A', 'K']
>>> original_pairs = [['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'],['D', 'E'], ['S', 'F'], ['B', 'C'], ['Y', 'V'], ['K', 'W']]
>>> fq = 5
>>> [[x]*fq for x in original_pairs if "".join(pair_no_change)!="".join(x)]
[[['D', 'E'], ['D', 'E'], ['D', 'E'], ['D', 'E'], ['D', 'E']], [['S', 'F'], ['S', 'F'], ['S', 'F'], ['S', 'F'], ['S', 'F']], [['B', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'C']], [['Y', 'V'], ['Y', 'V'], ['Y', 'V'], ['Y', 'V'], ['Y', 'V']], [['K', 'W'], ['K', 'W'], ['K', 'W'], ['K', 'W'], ['K', 'W']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more for loop

```
def frequency(original_pairs, pair_no_change, fq):
    updated_pairs = list(list())
    for pair in original_pairs:
        if pair != pair_no_change:

            for i in range(fq):

                updated_pairs.append([pair[0], pair[1]])

        else:
            continue
    return updated_pairs
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `pair[0] *= fq`.
If the `pair[0] = 'Q'` and `fq = 3` then the result will be a string `'QQQ'` and you are just pushing that result into updated_pairs.
So use a for loop to push into the updated_pairs array.

```
def frequency(original_pairs, pair_no_change, fq):
    updated_pairs = list(list())
    for pair in original_pairs:
       if pair != pair_no_change:
           for i in range(fq):
               updated_pairs.append([pair[0], pair[1]])
       else:
           continue
return updated_pairs
```